# Difference to get string with gets and fgets in C

Tags: c, stdin

My question is, what is the difference between these two pieces of code.

1)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define  SIZE 7

int main()
{
    int strSize;
    char tim[SIZE];
    printf("Enter the time (format xx:yy)= ");
    // for example when I type 14:45
    gets(tim); 
    int i;
    for (i=0; tim[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    }
    strSize=i;
    // result of program turns as 5.
    printf("%d", strSize);
    return 0;     
}
```

2. 

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define  SIZE 7

int main()
{
    int strSize;
    char tim[SIZE];
    printf("Enter the time (format xx:yy)= ");
    // when I type again 14:45
    fgets(tim, SIZE, stdin);
    int i;
    for (i=0; tim[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    }
    strSize=i;
    // result turns as 6
    printf("%d", strSize);
    return 0;     
}
```

I also use strlen to see if there is really a difference between these two methods. And strlen also give different values.

Comment: Function `gets()` is obsolete and is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: So their difference is no longer relevant, although you should be aware that `fgets()` retains the newline. Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Besides the detail that `gets` is obsolete and dangerous, what is unclear for you? Reading the documentation would reveal that there is a `'\n'` in the buffer.

Comment: By checking whether there is a newline, you'll know if the buffer was big enough. And in the `gets()` one, what happens when you enter `"This string is far too long for the buffer"`?

Answer (score 3):

Differences:

- `fgets` is a standard library function, `gets` is a withdrawn function no longer used. It was flagged obsolescent somewhere in the 1990s (30 years ago!) and finally removed entirely in the year 2011 (13 years ago!). So if your learning material mentions `gets`, there's a good reason to suspect that said learning material was written by the dinosaurs.
- `fgets` can read from any stream/file, `gets` can only read from `stdin`.
- `fgets` gives the opportunity to set a maximum size before it stops reading.
- `fgets` stops reading upon encountering new line `\n` and then stores that new line character in the read string. Which can explain differences in string length.
- `gets` is highly dysfunctional since it has no maximum limit and therefore prone to buffer overruns. `fgets` is only somewhat dysfunctional since it on one hand it has a maximum limit (good) but it returns no information of how many characters that were actually read (bad), like any half-decently designed function does. Better functions surely exist for your specific target, but those functions won't be portable.

Best practice is to avoid the whole of `stdio.h` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The **TL;DR;** answer is that `fgets()` includes a `size` parameter (it reads up to n-1 characters) whereas `gets()` is unconstrained by size.

This makes any system using `gets()` vulnerable to buffer-overflow, simply by entering too many characters.

As such `gets()` should **NEVER BE USED** - to reinforce this, ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14 (the custodians of the C standard) have removed this function from the standard!

Example (for your `tim[7]`) and "The cat sat on the mat":

`gets()` returns "The cat sat on the mat\0", overwriting the next block of memory (or stack)
`fgets()` returns "The ca\0".